# Codewars: Take a 10 Minute Walk... (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

> You live in the city of Cartesia where all roads are laid out in a perfect grid. You arrived ten minutes too early to an appointment, so you decided to take the opportunity to go for a short walk. The city provides its citizens with a Walk Generating App on their phones -- everytime you press the button it sends you an array of one-letter strings representing directions to walk (eg. ['n', 's', 'w', 'e']). You know it takes you one minute to traverse one city block, so create a function that will return true if the walk the app gives you will take you exactly ten minutes (you don't want to be early or late!) and will, of course, return you to your starting point. Return false otherwise.

Here's my code:

```
def isValidWalk(walk)
  vertical = 0
  horizontal = 0
  
  for each in walk do
    if walk = 'n'
      vertical = vertical + 1
    elsif walk = 's'
      vertical = vertical - 1
    elsif walk = 'w'
      horizontal = horizontal + 1
    elsif walk = 'e'
      horizontal = horizontal - 1
    end
  end
  
    count = walk.length

    if vertical == 0 && horizontal == 0 && count == 10
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
    
    end
```

The program failed the condition:

> "Should return true for a valid walk."

Any ideas why? And any suggestions on which of the current code or the commented out portion is better?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both of your attempts to do an `each` block have syntax issues.

Your first (commented out) attempt (`walk.each`) is generally considered the preferred syntax in ruby. But you are using `=` instead of `==`, which is why it did not work. You should have written:

```
walk.each do |x| 
  if x == 'n'
    vertical = vertical + 1
  elsif x == 's'
  # ...
  end
end
```

`=` **assigns a value**, whereas `==` **queries** whether two values are equal (and returns `true`/`false`).

Your second attempt was also making this `=` vs `==` mistake, and in addition you are also using the wrong variable. You could have written this like:

```
for value in walk do
  if value == 'n'
    vertical = vertical + 1
  # ...
  end
end
```

One final note is that you can simplify the code slightly by writing e.g.:

```
vertical += 1
```

Here is a complete, simplified version of the code:

```
def valid_walk?(walk)
  vertical = 0
  horizontal = 0

  walk.each do |x| 
    if x == 'n'
      vertical +=  1
    elsif x == 's'
      vertical -= 1
    elsif x == 'w'
      horizontal += 1
    elsif x == 'e'
      horizontal -= 1
    end
  end

  count = walk.length
  vertical == 0 && horizontal == 0 && count == 10
end
```

You could improve it even further by using a guard clause (check that the array is valid **before** looping through it, for better performance!) and using a `case` statement. But I'll leave that as an exercise for you, if you're interested.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much for such a detailed response!

Comment: Beginners might benefit from using `case` more often as it's basically impossible to foul up `=` vs. `==` and accidentally assign. It's also more efficient than a long `if`/`elsif` chain. `case x` and then break out all the possibilities.